# how to submit file using jquery to codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

May I ask for your help guys!

I am trying to upload a file and passing all the data to codeigniter controller using jquery.

my view file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Item Image</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <input class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="" id="itemImage" name="itemImage"  data-parsley-required="true" />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="add_item();">Sumit</button>
<script>
function add_item(){
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin_newitem/add_item'); ?>',
         {
            itemId          : $('#itemId').val(),
            itemImage       : $('#itemImage').val()
         },
         function(data){
              if(data.result=='SUCCESS'){
                $('#itemId').val('');
                $('#itemImage').val('');
                   //show success

                  }else{
                    //show error
                  }
            },'json'
        );
    }
</script>
```

My controller:

```
function add_item(){
    $this->output->set_status_header(200);
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $itemId          = $this->input->post('itemId');
    $itemImage       = $this->input->post('itemImage');;
    $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH.'../assets_main/img/item/');
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '200';
    $config['max_height']  = '200';
    $file_name = $config['file_name'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$itemImage){
        $jdata['result']  = "FAILED";
        $jdata['message'] = "upload error.";
        $jdata['field']   = "itemImage";
        echo json_encode($jdata);
        exit();
    }
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $jdata['message'] = "Thank you for purchasing our item!";
    $jdata['result']  = "SUCCESS";                  
     echo json_encode($jdata); 
     exit();
}
```

I was able to get the ItemId, and ItemImage but when I check the folder where the image is suppose to be located, it's not there. I think I fail to capture the real file, so, is there a way for me to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, I believe that you are forgetting to actually do the upload, the code igniter documentation might help:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

With this correctly implemented, I think your code should look something similar to:

```
function add_item(){
    $this->output->set_status_header(200);
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $itemId          = $this->input->post('itemId');
    $itemImage       = $this->input->post('itemImage');;
    $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH.'../assets_main/img/item/');
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '200';
    $config['max_height']  = '200';
    $file_name = $config['file_name'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    //THE MISSING LINE
    if($this->upload->do_upload()){
        //THE FILE HAS NOW BEEN UPLOADED
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $jdata['message'] = "Thank you for purchasing our item!";
        $jdata['result']  = "SUCCESS";                  
        echo json_encode($jdata); 
        exit();
    }else{
        //NO FILE UPLOADED
        $jdata['result']  = "FAILED";
        $jdata['message'] = "upload error.";
        $jdata['field']   = "itemImage";
        echo json_encode($jdata);
        exit();
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried that already but it didn't work. I'm thinking maybe because the controller wasn't able to catch the file to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thinking, having used CI and tried to do this same thing, is that you can't do file uploads via AJAX without a special plugin such as this:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Specifically, this file upload portion:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Simply trying to send a post with the val of a file input will not work, I don't believe - though maybe more modern browsers are able to handle that now.

Comment: do you have any other suggestion what I can do with this? if this really will not gonna work, most likely I will gonna do this again with the normal uploading of codeigniter. thanks for the answer man. I appreciate it.

Comment: You just sort of have to set it up as the plugin shows, and make a php page to catch the upload, similar to what you have. Sorry, that's about all I know to say.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I just decided that if user will upload image then he/she needs to click the submit with img or submit without img.